# Swift, Network call with Completion Handler not working

Tags: swift, firebase, networking, closures, completionhandler

I am reading data from Firebase and want to use a closure to be aware when the call is complete. My code looks like this:

```
func fetchGameTexts(gameType : String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()){
    var fetchedArray = [String]()

    ref.child("GameTexts").child("JagHarAldrig").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot, error) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            let userDictValue = userDict.values
            fetchedArray.append("\(userDictValue.first!)")

        }
        completion(fetchedArray)
    }

}
```

Calling the function:

```
let FetchGameText = FetchGameTexts()
    FetchGameText.fetchGameTexts(gameType : "JagHarAldrig") { fetchedArray in
        print("inside completion handler : \(fetchedArray)")
    }
```

Now the network call works as expected but not the completion handler, which prints the array time after time, instead of when the call is complete.

I tried to move the "completion(fetchedArray)" inside the if let block and also outside of the ref call. Did not work either.

Appreciate all help.

**EDIT:**

Changed the called method as follows and the callback works, but the output prints keys, values and extra info i don't want. I only need the values. Any Ideas?

```
func fetchGameTexts(gameType : String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()){
    var fetchedArray = [String]()

    ref.child("GameTexts").child(gameType).observe(.value) { (snapshot, error) in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            fetchedArray.append("\(child)")
        }
        completion(fetchedArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a dispatch queue that waits for the call to be finished and notify when done.

Comment: This `fetchedArray.append("\(child)")` will append each of the child snapshots to the array (as a string?), which is why you're getting all of the data for each child. Your question says 'the value'; that's easy to do but we need to understand what that value is to propose and accurate solution. Can you include a snippet of your firebase structure (as text please, no images) and indicate what data you're trying to get to? Also, while .value 'works', as the node grows it may contain a LOT of data, and that can overwhelm the device so that should probably be avoided. I have two options.

Comment: Also, what are you doing with the data? As is, you're casting all of it to an array of gigantic strings which doesn't make it very useful - maybe it does for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong with how you implemented the completion and the Firebase call. The completion block is called multiple times whenever the parent is changed (or if my memory serves right, it will be fired for every child you currently have at the beginning), because you're listening to `.childAdded`. It will continue to do so, until you remove the listener from the `ref`.

My assumption is that you're trying to fetch all the children, so you'd need to use `.value` in order to get all of them at once.

For that, this may also be of help:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Comment: Thank you, i read through the docs ans came up with this which makes the completion handler work, however now the output is not as i wish. I only want the values not the keys in the output, check my edit.

Comment: You're nearly in the clear, `child` is probably a `Dictionary`, so you may get the items which are necessary by handpicking them. It's another assumption though, you should also print the `child` and share what's actually been inside that.

Comment: @olle This is correct in that .childAdded initially iterates over all the child nodes one at a time but then after that *only fires when new child nodes are added*. But,  `.value` can be dangerous as it loads ALL of the data in the node *every time there's a change of any kind*. That's pushing around a lot of data and if it's a large node can overwhelm the devices memory. For smaller datasets or nodes that will not grow, it's fine, other than that, it should be avoided and use more granular functions like .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved.

Comment: @Jay Quoting from Firebase itself, "This pattern (.value) can be useful when you want to fetch all children of a list in a single operation, rather than listening for additional child added events."

But I agree with you, unless the value observation is a single event, which it should be the case here.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but read the section right above that *Attaching a FIRDataEventTypeValue observer to a list of data will return the entire list of data*, and that can overwhelm the device if the node is large. In other words, .childAdded fires when a child is added.  .value events **also** fire when a child is added, along with *any other change*. If you look at the code in the question, any time *anything* changes the entire node re-loads. Most importantly, all of the data is stuffed into a String making it not very useful.

Comment: I see your point, and I'm telling that `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` should be used, so it will only trigger once.

I don't get the point of "stuffing data into String", observing a single event of value would return a list, preserving the data structure.

In summary, the optional way to be sure that you have received all the children data, you should use `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)`. You cannot be sure whether you got the all children with `childAdded` at the beginning, although you may achieve that with some sort of a timer.

Comment: *You cannot be sure* is not accurate. `.childAdded` is **guaranteed** to iterate over all child nodes and then leave an observer for additional .childAdded events. And 100% yes to using `.observeSingleEvent` so as to not leave an observer on the node. It would be super helpful if you could provide code in your answer to demonstrate what your solution is as I think it's the right direction and the OP could probably use some help with that piece since the completion handler is implemented correctly. Just keep in mind the amount of data loaded with .value could be significant.